# API Management- Self Hosted Gateway backend URL

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I try to install a self-hosted gateway for Azure API Management in a Docker Desktop Kubernetes cluster.
After the installation the heartbeat result is ok.

[image]

I have deployed a web API service for testing and try to configure the backend URL using the DNS Name CStandard convention for Kubernetes as:

http://[servicename].[namespace].svc.cluster.local/api/v1/WeatherForecast/_me

but when I try to test the call in API management I have `500 Internal Server Error: The remote name could not be resolved`

How can I set the backend URL for a service in a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: your hosting platform (docker desktop) should be able to resolve the DNS name of your backend url, otherwise, SHG will fail to connect to it.

Comment: Yes, i try to ping the name inside the pods of the gateway , and it resolve the name with the correct ip